# Intersect with Linestring rather than Polygon

Tags: gml, ogc

The code below filters by given polygon coords but I need to do the same except with a linestring. How do I find polygons that intersect with a polyline?

```
<ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Intersects>
        <ogc:PropertyName>SHAPE</ogc:PropertyName>
        <gml:Polygon srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
            <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                <gml:LinearRing>
                    <gml:coordinates>" + coords + "</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
        </gml:Polygon>
    </ogc:Intersects>
</ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply change the `Polygon` with a `LineString`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ogc:Filter xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ogc:Intersects>
    <ogc:PropertyName>SHAPE</ogc:PropertyName>
    <gml:LineString>
      <gml:coordinates>0.0,0.0 1.0,1.0</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:LineString>
  </ogc:Intersects>
</ogc:Filter>
```